# Php умный парсинг ini файла

Tags: ооп, php.ini, php

Есть класс Configs,  и в этой же папке  где находится скрипт, располагается файл настроек core.ini (упростил чтобы не путаться еще с путями). Вопрос, как правильно им воспользоваться? Пока использую:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("core.ini", true);

$host =      $ini['MYSQL settings']['server'];
$dbuser=     $ini['MYSQL settings']['user'];
$dbpassword= $ini['MYSQL settings']['password'];
$usedb=      $ini['MYSQL settings']['usedb'];
$userstable= $ini['MYSQL settings']['userstable'];
```

А хотелось бы автоматически определять переменные.

```
class Configs{
// Holds an instance
private static $instance;
private $data;

// Prevents the direct object creation of the class.
private function __construct() {
    $this->load();
}

public static function singleton(){
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
        $c = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $c;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

// Prevents the user from clonning the instance.
public function __clone(){
    trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
}

function __set($var, $value){
    $this->data[$var] = $value;
}

function __get($var){
    return $this->data[$var];
}

//Loads values from the core.ini file
function load(){
    $core = parse_ini_file(CONFIGS . DS . 'core.ini', true);
    foreach($core as $key => $value){
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}

//Returns the DATA array
function getArray(){
    return $this->data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в смысле автоматически?

Если хотите с помощью класса установить конфиг, делайте так:

```
Config::singleton()->usedb = 'database';
```

Если хотите получить конфиг, то так:

```
echo Config::singleton()->usedb; // или вместо echo используйте что-то другое
```

Comment: автоматически: так чтобы не вводить поэлементно, а сразу  $usedb присваивалось то значение из ini ,  и так со всеми элементами из файла

Comment: а зачем вам это именно в переменной ? сделайте массив $config и в нем эти параметры тащите.